# Android 2.3.4: poor animation performance on underpowered device -- do I need to do my own animations?

Tags: android, animation, graphics

I've got some hardware running Android 2.3.4, and need to implement a simple demo showing an image and a couple of text fields moving around on the screen.  I'm currently using the Translate animation, which looks ok in the emulator, however works very poorly when run on the device.

So I tried using my own timer, updating the view positions within a RelativeLayout, and that made it a bit better, but things still aren't as smooth as I'd like.  A port of Angry Birds on this particular device runs fine, which makes me think I'm going to have to implement my own animations drawing on a SurfaceView.

Is that my best alternative for this version of Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably less a function of the version of the OS than it is crappy hardware.  I'm guessing it's a single core older phone.  If you're limited by hardware I do agree that your best solution will be to use the native window API (http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/) and draw things to a Surface.

I was doing some work on an old Nexus 1 and it was painful.  Nexus S wasn't slightly better.  In both cases dropping down into native code sped things up enough to be (barely) acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback.